# Use Zebra Scanner with ZXing instead of camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, zxing, zebra-printers

I followed this tutorial to set up ZXing for scanning barcodes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwVtlT3E7fw&ab_channel=GeraldVersluisGeraldVersluis

However, I want to use the scanner on my Zebra device rather than camera. How can I go about this?

I just have a simple label that displays the scanned barcode results.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="scanResultText"/>
            <zxing:ZXingScannerView IsScanning="True" OnScanResult="ZXingScannerView_OnScanResult" />
</StackLayout>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void ZXingScannerView_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                scanResultText.Text = result.Text;
            });
}
```

Comment: read the manual for your device.  Hardware based scanners usually appear (or have the option to) as keyboards and will just send their input to any text control that has focus.  There is usually little if any coding involved

Comment: That gives me the actual numbers of the barcode but how do I parse the data?

Comment: Barcodes can contain anything, it's up to you on how to parse it.

Comment: You don't need a library. Just configure the scanner as a keyboard. Zebra has a configuration tool

Comment: barcodes are just encoded alphanumeric strings.  They are typically just identifiers that you use to lookup data in some other system

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks! Is there a way for me to determine if the data is from the scanner or keyboard?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of per se, although we've configured ours to append a newline to all barcodes.